# Can a GKE multi-zone cluster be migratd to a single-zone one?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I currently have a GKE multi-zone cluster and I will like to move it to a single-zone one, the only option I can think is to create a second cluster and do the migration manually.

Is there a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately after reading [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-cluster) and [cluster concepts](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/regional-clusters) I noticed that you cannot change the zones after cluster creation.

Here are the notes from the docs:

> **Note:** After you create a cluster, you cannot change it from zonal to regional, or regional to zonal.
>
> **Note:** Once you create a multi-zonal cluster, you cannot convert it to a single-zone or regional cluster.

For migration purposes there is project worth checking out called [Velero](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero). Here`s a good [medium article](https://blog.doit-intl.com/google-kubernetes-engine-cluster-migration-with-velero-4a140b018f32) with migration using it.

Comment: If this was helpful would you consider accepting and [upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the answer?